# using FileSavePicker to save files without prompting

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I am developing a Windows 8 app using C# in which I have to save an audio automatically after it has finished recording. I used FileSavePicker and everytime it opens a file save window. However, I want it to happen without the prompt. I have already entered the file name and the encoding in the FileSavePicker object. The only thing remaining is saving it quietly. Please Help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer by using `CreateFileAsync`

The usual syntax for saving (under FileSavePicker) was:

`var mediaFile = await _fileSavePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();`

If I replaced it with:

`StorageFile mediaFile = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.CreateFileAsync("file1.mp3",Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);`

The problem was solved! I also had to add music library in the app capabilities.

Comment: For this to work for me I had to go to the package.appxmanifest and check the library.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this. If you want to write to a file that has been picked before, you can use the [`FutureAccessList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207457). If you want to write to a file in the `ApplicationDataContainer` folder, you shouldn't use the `FileSavePicker`. If you request access to a `KnownFolder`, you also don't need to use the picker.

Using [`KnownFolders`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.knownfolders) is about as dead easy as possible. Consider wanting to access the `Music Library` for instance (assuming you have the Music Library capability), and then creating a file in said library.

```
StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;
StorageFile file = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync(myFilename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

That's all it takes. You can look up some guides or questions for proper use of `file` for reading/writing.

Comment: I want to save the file to the music library. What shall I use?

Comment: You can either request access in the app declarations (the music library is a Known library which you can pre-request access to) or you can request that they choose the music library folder, then store that folder in the `FutureAccessList`.

Comment: I have included music library in the app capabilities. I do not know what exactly I need to do for saving a file in the folder( I am a beginner ). I want the file to get saved every time without the user's confirmation once each recording is complete. Please tell me in detail.
**Thank You**

Comment: Added an example for using a KnownFolder